# Does Wikidata contain the data from the Wikipedia {{distinguish}} template?

Tags: wikidata

Wikipedia uses the [{{Distinguish}}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Distinguish) template for pages whose subject is easily confused with another subject. For example, the [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo) [Congo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_the_Congo) countries are frequently confused with each other, so their Wikipedia articles warn the user:

[image]

This establishes a N-M-relationship between Wikipedia subjects.

Are these relationships somehow available in Wikidata?

Comment: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q971#P1889